# Show content based on drop down value

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm needing to show some content based on the value of a select drop down.

Something along the lines of:

```
<?php
$user=(types_render_field("user", array("raw"=>"true")));
if ($user== 'DS')
{ ?>
```

Show signature content for user DS

```
<?php } else if ($user== 'OS') ?>
```

Show signature content for user OS

I just can't seem to find an answer online, does anyone know if this is possible or has a solution.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps switch() will work for you? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

```
switch($user){
   case "DS":
       $content = '';
       break;
   case "OS":
       $content = '';
       break;
}
```

Comment: I changed $content = to echo & it works perfectly. Thanks very much for the quick reply & the help

Comment: No problem :) remember to mark the question as "answered" :)

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, how would I do that?

Comment: There should be a Checkmark/ thing at the right side of a answer,